# starting to lap at the shores

Tags: word-usage

Does "lap" here mean "to wash or move in small waves with a light, slapping or splashing sound"?

> It wasn’t long into the pandemic before Simon Carley realized we had an evidence problem. It was early 2020, and COVID-19 infections were starting to lap at the shores of the United Kingdom, where Carley is an emergency-medicine doctor at hospitals in Manchester.

Source: Nature     [How COVID broke the evidence pipeline](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01246-x)

Comment: What are some other meanings of "lap"? Do you think any of them would fit better, r not?

Comment: "Overlap" might work. But when "lap" was collocated with "shore", it most likely means "wash against or beat upon."

Comment: Exactly. But "beat upon" is **not** right. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lap) has "*wash against (something) with a gentle rippling sound*." It's probably related to animals drinking: cats lapping up milk, for example.

Comment: The analogy or metaphor is with incoming tides and floods. As river or sea water begins to rise along banks and shorelines it usually 'laps' gently at or over the levees or other defences. At that time it is not obviously threatening but as it gets higher, even it it rises slowly, it can be devastating.